# How to use countifs function to count multiple criteria involving dates?

Tags: excel

```
=COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$20000,MONTH(8),$K$2:$K$20000,"U")
```

Where C column is the list of dates, K column is another criteria i want to meet.

Here I'm attempting to count whenever Column C is within the month of August and Column K value is "U", the above formula i used return 0 where I expecting some values.

Not sure what is the problem with my formula.

Comment: this looks like a spreadsheet formula, why is this tagged `c`?

Comment: If the August is of a particular year, you can use criteria like `...$C$2:$C$20000,">="&date(2015,8,1),$C$2:$C$20000,"<" & date(2015,9,1) ...`  The date(...) function can be replaced with a cell reference.  If the August is any August of any year, then use `SUMPRODUCT` as recommended by user3964075

Comment: This is actually the first time i post, i tagged c because its the only recommended tag? Sorry if i cause confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Month() formula won't work inside COUNTIFS formula, you can use SUMPRODUCT instead:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH($C$2:$C$20000)=8)*($K$2:$K$20000="U"))
```

Or add an extra column to your data, calculate month in it, and use COUNTIFS with the new column.